# Where and when is the need of destruction in object oriented programming in php language?

Tags: php, oop

I often use constructor in object oriented programming with php language but i have never got the need of destructor. Can anybody knows the use of destructor?

Comment: The php manual might help - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php.
And for the note, don’t call the destructor explicitly http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/11/14/php-dont-call-the-destructor-explicitly/

Answer (score 2):

__destruct() function automatically calls by PHP when object is no longer in use or program terminated.

Most of the time you no need to write __destruct() function. You can write your own destructor function if you want to add additional task to be done like save class variables is database before destruct class.

Answer (score -1):

The Destructor is like Constructor, but this one is used to liberate memory of objects in your program, if you are developing a big system, it's very recommended to clear the memory used for you System in order to perform the speed of your System.
As we know, we use the constructor to init some features of our class, the destructor is for clear the memory used for thoses features.

Comment: You're right for C. For Php, this is plain false. You should let the garbage collector, which is optimized, do this. Destructors in Php are used for other things, but *not for "clearing the memory"*.